# CustomAdapter getCount() first returning a positive count, but then returning a 0 right after

Tags: android, android-adapter, custom-adapter

I have made a custom adapter so that I can make a custom list view. The custom adapter takes in an ArrayList of my own RowItem class, and is supposed to populate my list view in my activity.

Nothing is coming up in my activity when I try and use the custom adapter. After some research I suspect that it might be my adapter's getCount function returning a 0, so I added some log info to check it.

What it's showing is that at first, my getCount does indeed return a positive value (100), but then literally the next moment after, it returns a zero, and continues to do so, which means my getView doesn't get called and list remains empty.

Here is my activity

```
package com.example.topsongsbyyear;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SongList extends AppCompatActivity implements Response.ErrorListener, Response.Listener<String> {
    String webUrl;
    String year;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    StringRequest stringRequest;
    RowItem row;
    ListView list;
    ArrayList<RowItem> rows;
    ListAdapter customAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        year = getIntent().getStringExtra("year");
        webUrl = "https://www.billboard.com/charts/year-end/" + year + "/hot-100-songs";
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_song_list);
        rows = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.all_list);
        list.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, webUrl, this, this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        requestQueue.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.i("----------------", "onErrorResponse executed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response){
        int rank = 1;
        Log.i("----------------", "onResponse executed");
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(response);
        parseHtml(doc);
        //call setData function in adapter
        //in setData, save the data and call notifyDataSetChanged (adapter method), which updates list view
    }

    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }

    public void parseHtml(Document doc){
        ArrayList<String> songList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> artistList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> imageUrls = new ArrayList<>();
        rows = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        Elements songs = doc.select(".ye-chart-item__title");
        for(Element song : songs){
            songList.add(song.text().toString());
        }
        Elements artists = doc.select(".ye-chart-item__artist");
        for(Element artist : artists){
            artistList.add(artist.text().toString());
        }
        Elements images = doc.select("div.ye-chart-item__image > img");
        for (Element image : images) {
            imageUrls.add(image.attr("src"));
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < songList.size(); i++){
            RowItem row = new RowItem(Integer.toString(i+1), songList.get(i), artistList.get(i), imageUrls.get(i));
            rows.add(row);
        }
        Log.i("----------------", "Just added to rows arrayList with songList size: " + songList.size() + " artistList size: " + artistList.size() + "and imageUrls size: " +imageUrls.size());
        Log.i("----------------", "Just before setting making customAdapter instance with row count " + rows.size());
        customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout, rows);
        list.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        if (customAdapter instanceof CustomAdapter){
            ((CustomAdapter) customAdapter).setData(rows);
        }
        Log.i("----------------","Adapter set after html parsed, with row count " + rows.size());




    }
}
```

and here is my Custom Adapter class

```
package com.example.topsongsbyyear;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<RowItem> rows;
    TextView songName;
    TextView artist;
    TextView rank;
    ImageView image;

    public CustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, ArrayList<RowItem> rows) {
        super(context, resource, rows);
        this.rows = rows;
        Log.i("--------------", "row filled with " + this.rows.size() + " elements");
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        //setData(rows);
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<RowItem> rows){
        clear();
        addAll(rows);
        Log.i("----------------", "setData called, cleared and then addAll(rows) with row count: " + rows.size());
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Log.i("----------------", "CustomAdapter getCount called, returning rows.size() which is: " + rows.size());
        return rows.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.i("---------------", "entered getView function");
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);

        //setData(rows);
        String singleSong = rows.get(position).getSong();
        String singleArtist = rows.get(position).getArtist();
        String singleRank = rows.get(position).getRank();
        String singleImage = rows.get(position).getPicUrl();
        songName = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        artist = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.artist);
        rank = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.rank);
        Log.i("----------------", "ADDED: " + singleRank + " " + singleSong + " by " + singleArtist +" TO LIST");
        image = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);

        songName.setText(singleSong);
        artist.setText(singleArtist);
        rank.setText(singleRank);

        Glide.with(context).
                load(singleImage).
                into(image);

        return customView;
    }

}
```

Here is the log with my messages, if that helps

```
05-10 19:49:54.610 29217-29217/com.example.topsongsbyyear I/----------------: onResponse executed
05-10 19:49:54.657 29217-29217/com.example.topsongsbyyear I/----------------: Just added to rows arrayList with songList size: 100 artistList size: 100and imageUrls size: 100
05-10 19:49:54.658 29217-29217/com.example.topsongsbyyear I/----------------: Just before setting making customAdapter instance with row count 100
05-10 19:49:54.658 29217-29217/com.example.topsongsbyyear I/--------------: row filled with 100 elements
05-10 19:49:54.658 29217-29217/com.example.topsongsbyyear I/----------------: CustomAdapter getCount called, returning rows.size() which is: 100
    CustomAdapter getCount called, returning rows.size() which is: 100
05-10 19:49:54.659 29217-29217/com.example.topsongsbyyear I/----------------: CustomAdapter getCount called, returning rows.size() which is: 0
05-10 19:49:54.659 29217-29217/com.example.topsongsbyyear I/chatty: uid=10086(com.example.topsongsbyyear) identical 2 lines
05-10 19:49:54.660 29217-29217/com.example.topsongsbyyear I/----------------: CustomAdapter getCount called, returning rows.size() which is: 0
    setData called, cleared and then addAll(rows) with row count: 0
    CustomAdapter getCount called, returning rows.size() which is: 0
    CustomAdapter getCount called, returning rows.size() which is: 0
    Adapter set after html parsed, with row count 0
05-10 19:49:54.675 29217-29217/com.example.topsongsbyyear I/----------------: CustomAdapter getCount called, returning rows.size() which is: 0
05-10 19:49:54.681 29217-29217/com.example.topsongsbyyear I/----------------: CustomAdapter getCount called, returning rows.size() which is: 0
05-10 19:49:54.842 29217-29217/com.example.topsongsbyyear I/----------------: CustomAdapter getCount called, returning rows.size() which is: 0
05-10 19:49:54.844 29217-29217/com.example.topsongsbyyear I/----------------: CustomAdapter getCount called, returning rows.size() which is: 0
05-10 19:49:55.057 29217-29241/com.example.topsongsbyyear I/chatty: uid=10086(com.example.topsongsbyyear) RenderThread identical 2 lines
```

Also, if my setData function is not called anywhere (either in my parseHtml or custom adapter constructor), my app crashes.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `ArrayAdapter` maintains a private `List` field for its dataset. When you pass `rows` in the `super` constructor call, its field then points to your `ArrayList`, which is at 100 items. So far, so good. However, you then call your `setData()` method, which calls `clear();` on `ArrayAdapter`, which clears its `List` field, but that's pointing to your `rows` `List`, so it gets cleared, and the subsequent `addAll()` call just adds an empty `List` to an empty `List`, so you're back to 0. Probably the easiest solution is to just get rid of your `ArrayList<RowItem> rows;` field, ...

Comment: ... and let `ArrayAdapter` handle the `List`. You can use `ArrayAdapter`'s `getItem()` method in place of all of your `rows.get()` calls, and just remove the `getCount()` override, as `ArrayAdapter` will handle it correctly. Alternatively, extend `BaseAdapter` instead, so you're the only one touching the `List`, and know exactly what happens where.

Comment: Hey Mike, I followed your advice and got rid of my ArrayList<RowItem> and used the ArrayAdapter's getItem() method instead, and it works! I also do not need my setData() method as well, all I have to do is call notifyDataSetChanged() in my constructor. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this.rows=rows; in your setData method and you will have it updated at any time.

Note that you are setting this.rows only in your CustomAdapter's constructor, and when you do setData you are not setting it. Also, calling clear(); in setData, is clearing your this.rows list because Array adapter holds a reference to list you are passing through super in the constructor.

Comment: Hi Marc. I already solved the issue thanks to Mike M.'s input. However I still appreciate the help! Thank you